# default bootstrap is overriding my custom css in react

Tags: css, reactjs, cdn

[Link to project picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Uclv.png)

I am creating a project in react and needed bootstrap. But it is overriding my custom css. Some of default bootstrap changing my headings. I have tried everything like putting my css link below bootstrap and also importing it into my index.js file but nothing working. i have attached the picture of my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try maybe using bootstrap as a dependency:

```
npm i bootstrap
```

and import in index.js:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

or even try a react-bootstrap dependency

```
npm i react-bootstrap
```

Bootstrap is written with !important rules, so they has the highest priority if given!
Maybe you can try inline css in React elements (although not recomended in a simple HTML)

All the best!

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't added any codes example or link of your live project, please check if CSS file has been linked properly. **Go to page source** and **click on styles.css**. It should open all your codes inside CSS file. If you can't open this file, or there's nothing found, you should check CSS file linking once again.
But if you can see css file properly but still not working, as a final option, you can use "**!important**" in CSS class. It will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install bootstrap as npm package using `npm i bootstrap`. Then place your `styles.css` in the src folder and import `styles.css` in your `App.jsx`.

   ```
   import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
   import './styles.css'
   ```
2. Or you can even try using `!important`. This will definitely work but you will need to to it every time you want to override a style.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, bootstrap adds `!important` to seemingly everything. In order to remove all of them you'll need to install the npm package instead of linking to a CDN (like you're currently doing). So:

`npm install bootstrap` or `yarn add bootstrap`

Then create an app.scss (naming is arbitrary here) and add the following lines

```
$enable-important-utilities: false; //this disables !important
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
```

Then, import that `app.scss` file into your `index.js` file:

`import './app.scss'`

The next time your run `npm start` (or whatever command you're using) it should generate a new css file to use. You may need to install sass if your project isn't already using it. But, that's beyond the scope of this answer.